# How to switch license servers for MATLAB clients?

Tags: licensing

Anyone know how you get a client to switch license servers? I just installed R2009a and typed in the wrong license server (we still have an old server running R2006, I pointed to that by mistake); I really don't want to uninstall/reinstall the whole @#$@#$ program again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had issues with redundant license servers in MATLAB.  Mathworks recommends using environmental variables, such as `MLM_LICENSE_FILE=27000@server1.com;27000@server2.com;27000@server3.com`

Comment: That worked -- thanks! OK, so my question now is, what does MATLAB use as a default if there is no MLM_LICENSE_FILE env var?

Comment: In the MATLAB/2009a folder in Program Files, there is a licenses folder, where you can put a USE_SERVER license.dat or network.lic file which Matlab can read.  I think the ENV variable takes precedence.